# How do you drag and drop a program from Start menu into system tray?

Tags: windows

How do you drag and drop a program from the Start menu into the system tray in Windows 7?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! This is a good place to get answers to good questions. As it stands, your question is lacking a fair bit of information that would make it easier for us to provide you with an answer. Could you provide a screenshot of where you would like the Start Menu items to end up? Upload to [https://imgur.com] and then [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/999365/edit) your question with the link to the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to add a program to the taskbar (the line at the bottom of your screen)?

If so, to add it to the taskbar, right-click on the program in the Start menu and choose "Pin to taskbar."

Comment: I think he/she means the "show more icons" popup thingy on the taskbar. http://yhoo.it/1ll1VOG